# ERROR Processor got uncaught exception. (kafka.network.Processor) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18 while starting Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

When try to start the kafka server 2.11, i got the below exception trace.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18
    at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.ApiKeys.forId(ApiKeys.java:68)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractRequest.getRequest(AbstractRequest.java:39)
    at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.<init>(RequestChannel.scala:79)
    at kafka.network.Processor$$anonfun$run$11.apply(SocketServer.scala:426)
    at kafka.network.Processor$$anonfun$run$11.apply(SocketServer.scala:421)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:421)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: 2.11 is not a real Kafka version. Which version are you really running? And what version of Java?

Comment: Yes,  you are right. I am using kafka version is 0.9 and java is java8.

Comment: You are trying to install Kafka? Why are you using such an old version?